# Best practice to handle actions on a list of items (front vs API)?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, rest, design-patterns

One of my projects is about books listings and books reviews. Once logged in, a user is redirected to a view where the most popular 20 books of the community are listed. Some of them could already be in the list of the user or reviewed by him.

My current approach:

- back-end (NodeJS + mongoDB Rest API): return the same list of 20 books populated with their reviews (comments + users) for all logged-in users
- front-end (React Native app): display the right button label ("owned" / "reviewed") after comparing the 20 books list data and the current user books (fetched user session).

How/where would you process the data? Would you recommand to handle this front-end data process in the back-end? (and return a list of books where each book is already identified as "isOwned" / "isReviewed" by the user?)

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to try to make as much as you can logic in the API not in front-end side.

Front-end side doesn't have the same efficiency of the servers so try to render only in the front-end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ahmad. I will code more logic in the API.